# Can I have problems if I connect to many SMTP from the same server?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, imap, swiftmailer

We have a SAAS app where we connect to customer's SMTP and IMAP servers in order to send and read email.

Can mail servers like Google, Yahoo, etc. backlist our IP or mark sent emails as spam because of too many connection from the same IP?

It's strange because one customer complained about this but we think that other related companies are not using any proxy.

Comment: Absolutely.  Gmail will blacklist anyone who appears to be doing stuff “out of the ordinary”.  Using OAUTH will mitigate some of that, but getting mail scopes now requires a lot of assurances that you’re not doing something weird and potentially external validation of your platform for security and privacy.

Comment: Yeah, oauth is discarded for now. Do you think using a proxy would help?

Comment: I mean, you can try to evade their anti-automated detection, but it will eventually catch up with you, and you'd better be prepared to change your business model/processes.  The major Email Providers have basically said "Accessing a User's Email is forbidden, unless you use these protocols and go through these hoops." As always, IANAL, but doing otherwise may violate the terms of services and open you/your company up to consequences.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question.